# Login session transferred to other user

Tags: security, session, coldfusion, lucee

I have kind of a strange problem. I have build a web application in Lucee. You need to login to use web application. It has happened, at least twice, that a login session has been transferred to an other user. To clarify what happen:

1. User 1 is logged in the application, the session is active
2. User 2 goes to the web application and is automatically logged in and sees "welcome to the application user 1".

As mentioned above this has happened at least twice since the application is live, so it sounds like an incident. Security wise this is a big problem because user 1 is an administrator and user 2 has a basic access profile.

My question: does anyone recognize this issue and can someone give my some advice how to troubleshoot this problem.

Thanks

Comment: How are you experiencing this issue?  Is this still in development?  Are you experiencing this through using the same browser (but different windows?)

Comment: This is in production. We are experiencing this because user 2 has called us to report the issue. To clarify user 1 and 2 have never met each other and there both using complete different computers, different networks, isp, locations etc..

Comment: I've only come across this issue when the users were on the same network using Firefox.  One of the more frequent advice I've heard about was turning on J2EE session management.  This was on CF8+, but I think the same thing can be applied here.

Comment: I've seen this with poorly controlled caching. Is it possible cached content generated for user 1 is being returned for user 2?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using session variables, this could happen with data being assigned to the incorrect scope in a CFC or with objects being stored incorrectly in the application scope or even a mash-up of both.

Make sure that your CFC functions are using the function local scope:

`var x = ""` or `local.x = ""`

otherwise, `x` will be in the variables scope of the CFC, where it can be manipulated by any function inside the CFC. This leads to data bleeding from one call to another across sessions. Try using [varscoper](https://github.com/mschierberl/varscoper) to scan your code for these issues.

Alternately, you could store an object that contains data for a user into the application scope or inside another object which is stored in the application scope. This could allow User A to access data meant for User B when they are logged in at the same time.

You need to do an audit of your code base for issues like this and go through your user session logic to verify where and how data is stored and accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Like one of the comments suggested could be the users were on the same network and/or they used a proxy such as [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) which would cache all incoming content. To check to see if it's a possibility take a look at the headers being sent out by your server and see if there are any headers related to caching (Cache-Control, Expires, Last-Modified, ETag).

if you want to prevent caching you could set the first example header in you application.cfc onRequestStart or to at least prevent user content being cached you could do some variation of the second example.

```
<cfscript>
    //EX 1
    header name="cache-control" value="no-cache"; //no caching by anything

    //EX 2
    if(loggedIn){
        header name="cache-control" value="private, max-age=<time_in_seconds>"; //allow browser to cache content
    }else{
        header name="cache-control" value="public, max-age=<time_in_seconds>"; //allow anything to cache content
    }
</cfscript>
```